# How to make scale of both Y-axes same in Composite chart in dc.js

Tags: scale, dc.js

I am plotting a composite chart in dc with two y-axis to compare two values (this year and last year) using the following code:

```
compositeChart.width(1200)
             .height(240)
             .margins({top: 10, right: 100, bottom: 70, left:80})
             .transitionDuration(800)
             .dimension(depValue)
             .elasticY(true)
             .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["AUTO & TIRES","BABY", "CLOTHING", "ELECTRONICS", "GARDEN", "GROCERY", "HEALTH", "HOME", "HOME IMPROVEMENT", "PHOTO", "SPORTS", "TOYS", "VIDEO GAMES"]))
             .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
             .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
             .compose([
                    dc.barChart(compositeChart)
                            .group(group,"This Year")
                            .clickFilterBehavior("replace")
                            .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                                console.log(d.value);
                                return d.value;
                            }),
                    dc.barChart(compositeChart)
                            .group(group1,"Last Year")
                            .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                                console.log(d.value);
                                return d.value;
                            })
                            .clickFilterBehavior("replace")
                             .title(function (d) {
                                var value = d.data.value ? d.data.value : d.data.value;
                                if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
                                return dateFormat(d.data.key) + "\n" + numberFormat(value);
                            })

                            .colors(["orange"])
                            .useRightYAxis(true)
                ])
            .yAxisLabel("This Year")

            .rightYAxisLabel("Last Year")
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .renderlet(function (chart) {
        chart.selectAll("g._1").attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + ", 0)");
    });
```

The charts are fine but the issue is that the scale of both the Y-axes(right and left) is not same and hence even though the value for last year is lesser than this year, the bar looks higher than that of this year.Is there a way I can set the scale of the graph to be the same?Any help would be appreciated.!!!

Comment: I am not clear why you are using both left and right axes when they should be the same scale. Ordinarily the left/right axes are used when the two series represent different units entirely.

Comment: Realised it later. Removed ".useRightYAxis(true)"..Stupid question to ask..Sorry..Can you take a look at this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483757/disable-filtering-on-click-for-second-series-in-composite-chart-in-dc-js